# Metasploit on Ubuntu 14.04 msfrpcd Gemfile "Can't modify frozen String" error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, metasploit

I followed the tutorial at https://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/

I chose rbenv over rvm to install Ruby. The installer led me to install ruby 2.4.2.

```
#ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]

#rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.1-28-gb943955
```

It worked at first but then everything went downhill. I feel like I'm just missing something very obvious. When I run...I get:

```
#sudo -E ./msfrpcd -U USER -P PASSWORD -a 127.0.0.1 -p 55554 -S
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`:
[!] There was an error while loading `metasploit-framework.gemspec`: 
can't modify frozen String. Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /opt/metasploit-framework/metasploit-framework.gemspec:112
#  -------------------------------------------
#    # This used to be depended on by nokogiri, depended on by wmap
>    if Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('2.3.0')
#      spec.add_runtime_dependency 'xmlrpc'
#  -------------------------------------------
. Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /opt/metasploit-framework/Gemfile:4
#  -------------------------------------------
#  #   spec.add_runtime_dependency '<name>', [<version requirements>]
>  gemspec name: 'metasploit-framework'
#
#  -------------------------------------------
```

This is also the critical line in the Armitage script "teamserver" that fails.

I'm not experienced with ruby other than Ruby on Rails almost 10 years ago. Again, I feel like I've missed something stupid with my lack of experience with ruby. Let me know if I can provide some more information.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you try running `gem update --system` and see if the error goes away?

Comment: Hey sorry I totally missed that comment. I've done that and it runs successfully but doesn't fix the problem.